# Checking weather Processor is setting any exchange message or not in Camel router

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am just trying to create a route with multiple processors. Is it possible check weather any particular processor is setting any exchange or not. I am trying to check message field in xml body if Message is hello then I am setting exchange body and send to queue3 if condition fails I should not send any message to queue3

XML Input:

```
<Header>
   <MessageID>1</MessageID>
   <Sender>ABC</Sender>
</Header>
<Body>
   <Message>Hello</Message>
</Body>
```

ROute:

```
from(queue1)
.process(processorA).to(queue2)
.process(processsorB).to(queue3)
.process(ProcessorC).to(queue4)
.end()
```

ProcessorB:

```
if(xmlmessage.getbody().getMessage() == "Hello")
{
  exchange.genIn().setBody("World");
} else {
  exchange.getIn().setBody(null);
}
```

In above route, I just want to check weather processorB is setting any exchange message or not. So can I do that in router? or Is there any other ways I can implement this logic. I tried different options but not working. open to any suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need check body for null after processorB do like below:

```
from(queue1)
.process(processorA).to(queue2)
.process(processsorB).to(queue3)
.choice()
 .when(body().isNotNull())
     .process(ProcessorC).to(queue4)
 .otherwise()
     //do something
 .endChoice()
 .end()
```

More info about [choice](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/choice-eip.html)